XPath doesn't take any effect without throwing any errors
I want to make a button in 2 of our views only visible to users of a specific group. In the sale.order view everything works as intended. There is similar view in the account.move model which I inherited the same way I did with the sales.order view.
This is the view thats works correctly
<odoo>
    <record id="view_sale_order_form_extension" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.extension</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_commission.view_order_agent_form_inherit"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_edit_agents'][@icon='fa-users']"
                   position="attributes">
                <attribute name="groups">sale_commission.group_sales_agent</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

And this one doesn't
<odoo>
    <record id="view_account_move_form_extension" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.commission.view.move.form.extension</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_commission.view_move_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_edit_agents'][@icon='fa-users']"
                   position="attributes">
                <attribute name="groups">sale_commission.group_sales_agent</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

The button is also added via XPath through an inherited view, this is how it is implemented:
<xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_line_ids']/tree//field[@name='price_subtotal']" position="after">
<button name="button_edit_agents" icon="fa-users" attrs="{'invisible': [                         '|',('commission_free', '=', True),('any_settled', '=', True),],'column_invisible': [('parent.move_type', 'not in', ['out_invoice', 'out_refund'])]}" type="object"/>
</xpath>

It doesn't give me any errors, when I change the name of the button in the last view it also tells me that I can't find the button. Also I see that the view is correctly registered as an inherited view of the view I wanted to inherit.
I am out of ideas right now, I think it must be something very simple and stupid that I can't see or not know about. So any idea how to debug this problem further would be a great help!
I tried to:

restart the server and also the vm, so I do not have any cache problems
trying to use a wrong button name within the xpath to check if it throws an error (it does, so it really finds the view and the button as it seems)
using different users with different groups
I also tried to make it invisible=1 instead just adding a group tag to check if this will work, it also doesn't


The the well problem has to be in one of sale_commission.view_move_form , account.move , sale.order.form.extension, as they're the only things that differ

In the account.move view I now inherited the original view instead of the inherited view that adds the button and it is working now even though I can't tell why it did work in the sale.order with inheriting the already inherited view and in the account.move it doesn't.
